# UIScrollView subview is memory released (removed) when it's used in conjunction with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, subviews

The example is very simple, a bunch of `UIImageView`s are added as subviews to a `UIScrollView`:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, 91, 91);

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageview];
        x+=95;
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, 91.0)];
        //define gestures
        //single tap for wide display
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wideDisplay:)];
        imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}
```

after a single tap on a `UIImageView`, it's sent to the `wideDisplay:` method to get displayed widely:

```
-(void)wideDisplay:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{

    UAModalPanel *wideScreen = [[UAModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    wideScreen.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0);

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.imageView = (UIImageView*)gesture.view;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 790, 500);

    [wideScreen.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:wideScreen];    

}
```

after adding the imageView to the modal view, this `UIImageView` is removed from the scrollview subviews. imageView is a strong property, but despite that, seems that it's loosing reference after being added to custom modal view, how to prevent it from being removed from the scrollview after selecting it?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you disposing and creating `self.imageView` each time you call `-wideDisplay:`?

Comment: Yes, as shown below, `self.imageView` is instantiated each time I select a `UIImageView` and calling the `wideDisplay:` method.

Comment: I don't understand why the subview is released from the scrollview after using it

Comment: views can only have one superview at a time. you move the image view from `self.scrollView` (where it was added in the first code snippet) to `widescreen.contentView`. If you move it to `widescreen.contentView`, it is removed from `self.scrollView`

Comment: Also you create a view `[[UIImageView alloc] init]` that you then discard immediately by reassigning `self.imageView`